# Navigating the CLI: replace text from specific character to specific character

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I am a VIM user learning Emacs commands for use in Bash. I know that on my systems I can use Vim-keybindings in Bash but I'd like to learn how to use it effectively in its default configuration.

Consider the following command which uploads a file to a web service:

```
$ time curl -F "status_file=@under1meg.txt" -F "baz=777&bin=123&alice=bob" http://somesite.com/internal/project/status/foo/add_status.php
```

I have a bunch of files to upload with different parameters. Here are some questions:

1. How might I easily **go back from the end of the line to *before* the `http` part**? The combination <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> only goes back per [a-z] block, so I must to this for each directory in the URL. Is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> the preferred way to go back? Notice that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> does delete back to the previous whitespace, so the idea of `<something> until whitespace` seems to exist.
2. How might I **delete back to the `@` character from the current cursor position**? Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> deletes until whitespace, so that won't help as the `@` character is buried in non-whitespace. I could <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>@</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to delete words until I get to where I need to be, but this is rather obtuse. Is there not a `delete until previous <something>` command?

Note that I am interested in learning how to use the default Bash configuration as I am more often than not SSHed into some webserver. I don't want to configure Zsh, Vim keybindings, or `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `"M-C-]" character-search-backward` so `M-C-] SPC` in this case will go before `http`
2. `M-C-] @` and then `C-k` to delete from point to the end of the line (although it seems that you only want to delete to where you were before. I don't know any better option than `M-d` for that). To my knowledge there is no `delete until previous <something>` defined by default

What I find very useful is `C-y` which "yanks" (pastes) the contents of the "kill ring". So when you do `C-u` (delete from point to the beginning of line) you can paste this back with `C-y` and pressing `M-y` after `C-y` will cycle through the other "kills" made before (`C-w`, `C-k` etc.)

Also good to know is `C-/` which is `undo`

If you want to know more, checkout `man readline` (readline is used by Bash) which has a neat section DEFAULT KEY BINDINGS:

```
       Emacs Standard bindings

       "C-@"  set-mark
       "C-A"  beginning-of-line
       "C-B"  backward-char
       "C-D"  delete-char
       "C-E"  end-of-line
       "C-F"  forward-char
       "C-G"  abort
       "C-H"  backward-delete-char
       "C-I"  complete
       "C-J"  accept-line
       "C-K"  kill-line
       "C-L"  clear-screen
       "C-M"  accept-line
       "C-N"  next-history
       "C-P"  previous-history
       "C-Q"  quoted-insert
       "C-R"  reverse-search-history
       "C-S"  forward-search-history
       "C-T"  transpose-chars
       "C-U"  unix-line-discard
       "C-V"  quoted-insert
       "C-W"  unix-word-rubout
       "C-Y"  yank
       "C-]"  character-search
       "C-_"  undo
       " " to "/"  self-insert
       "0"  to "9"  self-insert
       ":"  to "~"  self-insert
       "C-?"  backward-delete-char

       Emacs Meta bindings

       "M-C-G"  abort
       "M-C-H"  backward-kill-word
       "M-C-I"  tab-insert
       "M-C-J"  vi-editing-mode
       "M-C-M"  vi-editing-mode
       "M-C-R"  revert-line
       "M-C-Y"  yank-nth-arg
       "M-C-["  complete
       "M-C-]"  character-search-backward
       "M-space"  set-mark
       "M-#"  insert-comment
       "M-&"  tilde-expand
       "M-*"  insert-completions
       "M--"  digit-argument
       "M-."  yank-last-arg
       "M-0"  digit-argument
       "M-1"  digit-argument
       "M-2"  digit-argument
       "M-3"  digit-argument
       "M-4"  digit-argument
       "M-5"  digit-argument
       "M-6"  digit-argument
       "M-7"  digit-argument
       "M-8"  digit-argument
       "M-9"  digit-argument
       "M-<"  beginning-of-history
       "M-="  possible-completions
       "M->"  end-of-history
       "M-?"  possible-completions
       "M-B"  backward-word
       "M-C"  capitalize-word
       "M-D"  kill-word
       "M-F"  forward-word
       "M-L"  downcase-word
       "M-N"  non-incremental-forward-search-history
       "M-P"  non-incremental-reverse-search-history
       "M-R"  revert-line
       "M-T"  transpose-words
       "M-U"  upcase-word
       "M-Y"  yank-pop
       "M-\"  delete-horizontal-space
       "M-~"  tilde-expand
       "M-C-?"  backward-kill-word
       "M-_"  yank-last-arg

       Emacs Control-X bindings

       "C-XC-G"  abort
       "C-XC-R"  re-read-init-file
       "C-XC-U"  undo
       "C-XC-X"  exchange-point-and-mark
       "C-X("  start-kbd-macro
       "C-X)"  end-kbd-macro
       "C-XE"  call-last-kbd-macro
       "C-XC-?"  backward-kill-line
```